# Getting error when connecting two Azure Analysis Services from child scripts

Tags: powershell, azure-analysis-services

I am working on PowerShell scripts. I have two scripts in those scripts I am connecting with two Azure Analysis Servers one by one. And these scripts are calling by the main script. I am getting errors

```
"Exception calling "Connect" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

My Scripts code is below

**Child1.ps1**

```
param(
    [String]
    $envName1,
    [String]
    $toBeDisconnect1
)

$loadInfo1 = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
$server1 = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server

if($toBeDisconnect1 -eq "No")
{
    $server1.Connect($envName1)
    return $server1
}
elseif($toBeDisconnect1 -eq "Yes")
{
    $server1.Disconnect()
    Write-Host $server1 " has been disconnected."
}
```

**Child2.ps1**

```
param(
    [String]
    $envName1,
    [String]
    $toBeDisconnect1
)

$loadInfo1 = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
$server1 = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server

if($toBeDisconnect1 -eq "No")
{
    $server1.Connect($envName1)
    return $server1
}
elseif($toBeDisconnect1 -eq "Yes")
{
    $server1.Disconnect()
    Write-Host $server1 " has been disconnected."
}
```

**MainParent.ps1**

```
param(
    $filePath = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\DBList.txt"
)

$command = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test1.ps1 –envName1 
asazure://aspaaseastus2.asazure.windows.net/mydevaas -toBeDisconnect1 No"
$Obj1 = Invoke-Expression $command
Start-Sleep -Seconds 15

$command1 = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test2.ps1 –envName2 
asazure://aspaaseastus2.asazure.windows.net/myuataas -toBeDisconnect2 No"
$Obj2 = Invoke-Expression $command1
```

**Error is below in MainParent.ps1**

```
 Exception calling "Connect" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an 
 object."
 At C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test1.ps1:13 char:5
 +     $server1.Connect($envName1)
 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException

 Exception calling "Connect" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an 
 object."
 At C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test2.ps1:13 char:5
        +     $server2.Connect($envName2)
        +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException
```

My AzureAnalysis Services dll version is 13.0.4495.10. I am sharing this info, may be it can be a issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `Invoke-Expression` is not passing the param `envName1`. I would rather call the child script normally like below:

```
$Obj1 = &"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test1.ps1" -envName1 "asazure://aspaaseastus2.asazure.windows.net/mydevaas" -toBeDisconnect1 No | select -Last 1

$Obj2 = &"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test2.ps1" -envName2 "asazure://aspaaseastus2.asazure.windows.net/myuataas" -toBeDisconnect2 No | select -Last 1
```

Comment: Where & How will you store the returned objects from child scripts?

Comment: I have executed your suggestion. I am getting the error as below for the test2.ps1 Exception calling "Connect" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test2.ps1:13 char:5
+     $server2.Connect($envName2)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException

Comment: For returned object I added | (pipe) at last if you noticed. And, can you include " (quote) around the envName1 value? Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Krishg, I can see you updated the answer, and that makes sense but somehow when I using the same way I am getting the following error. At line:1 char:149
+ ... westus.asazure.windows.net/mydevbiaas" -toBeDisconnect1 "No" | $Obj1
+                                                                     ~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline

Comment: what happens when you remove the pipe at the end or wrap the first part within ().

Comment: If I wrap the first part in the bracket and do not remove/not remove the pipe sign, the error sustains. but If I remove the pipe sign and do not wrap the first part in () brackets. It executes but $Obj is not recognizable; means $Obj1 does not have any object 9r property.

Comment: Exception calling "Connect" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\Users\User1\test1.ps1:13 char:5
+     $server1.Connect($envName1)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException
 
same error for test1.ps1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222726/discussion-between-krishg-and-ashish-bejovial).

Comment: which version of Microsoft.AnalysisServices you are using? I have updated my question by attaching a screenshot of the dll.

Comment: It was a dll version issue.

Answer (score 0):

`$command = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test1.ps1 –envName1  asazure://aspaaseastus2.asazure.windows.net/mydevaas -toBeDisconnect1 No"`

Look closely at the hyphen before `envName1`. It's actually  – (en-dash) instead of - (hyphen). That's the reason envName1 is not being passed. The second param `toBeDisconnect1` has it correct.

How to know the difference? - (hyphen) is shorter than – (en-dash) :)